# Auto Layout strange behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am a little bit confused. I have a UILabel and a UITextField having a strange behavior in the view.
I didn't use any code to place this two object in the view just drag and drop in the view and giving the constrain.

The UITextField should follow the following constrain "Bottom Space to Bottom Layout" which at minute I give the value 20. At run time the UITextField is following the constrain but when I change the view and a than I go back, the UITextField and obviously the UILabel that follow the UITextField is like they change this constrain under the Bottom Layout and I cannot see any more the UITextField.

Please Help if possible.
Thanks a lot

Comment: How you changed the view? Maybe you just removed NSTextField from superview? no?

Comment: The App has two view is TabBar App change view means when I go to view number 2 and than back to view number 1.

Comment: @Vytautas he is talking about iOS not Mac OS X. So he is dealing with UITextFields.

Comment: Ah, yes. typo. But it doesn't change anything.